# Rails resources routes for admin namespace, error when generating a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, simple-form, rails-routing

I have an `admin` namespace in routes with `users` controller:

```
namespace :admin do
   resources :users
end
```

So i have users_controller.rb in /admin folder, and a User model. In my _form partial i am trying to create a form for both new and edit actions, but when i try to create it using this:

> = simple_form_for @user do |f|

I am receiving in error in both edit and new actions:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `user_path' for...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try in the form with,

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @user] do |f|
```